# Netbeans visual editor suddenly flawed

Tags: java, swing, exception, netbeans, jtabbedpane

I am currently developing a small application for my exams next month. I am using the visual editor of Netbeans.

Suddenly it stopped working, giving me the exception at the end of the thread.

It appears it has something to do with my Tabbed Pane containing a panel called StuderendePanel.

Is anyone familiar with this issue, and how can I fix it?

[image]

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: View.StuderendePanel
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:252)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:191)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:806)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Do a clean and build, this refresh the cache. If that doesn't work, close netbeans, delete the cache, open netbeans and do another clean and build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now solved the problem.

We had our GUI to pass our controller object to our `Studerende` panel. However, when Netbeans calls the initComponents method of the GUI, the controller was not initialized, and therefore didn't work.